# HttpWebRequest Parallel Programming Handle Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest, task-parallel-library

I want to convert this into parallel programming that handles the exceptions as well.

```
    public List<ExcelRecord> GetReport(List<ExcelRecord> records, string type)
    {

        foreach (ExcelRecord rec in records)
        {                
            CheckHealth(rec);
        }

        return records;
    }

    private void CheckHealth(ExcelRecord rec)
    {
        string uri=rec.Url;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);          


        try
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, errors) => true;

            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36";
            WebResponse wr = req.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
            rec.StatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)wr).StatusCode;
            rec.Output = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();               


        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            if (wex.Response != null)
            {
                var pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                                      .ReadToEnd();
                rec.StatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusCode;

                rec.ErrorText = pageContent;
                rec.IsHtmlText = true;
            }
            else
            {
                rec.ErrorText = wex.Message;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rec.ErrorText = ex.Message;

        }
    }
```

I tried this for parallel.

```
   private void CheckHealth(string uri, ExcelRecord rec)
    {

     HttpWebRequest wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reqstString);

    var taskResp = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(wreq.BeginGetResponse,
                                                    wreq.EndGetResponse,
                                                    null);

     taskResp.ContinueWith(tsk => tsk.Result.GetResponseStream())
                                .ContinueWith((Task<Stream> trs) =>
                                {
                                  //Logic to update records
                                }
    }
```

But not sure how to handle the WebException and other exception I handled above . In parallel code, I get exception at `taskResp.ContinueWith(tsk => tsk.Result.GetResponseStream())`

**How to make the parallel to handle exception and update the records as well?**

`I am using .Net 4.0 Framework. So no async or await for me`

Comment: You can use async and await on 4.0 as well. This continuation nastiness goes away then.

Comment: `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, errors) => true;` is a memory leak. The callbacks will accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a look at the TaskContinuationOptions. You might be able to write something like:

```
  taskResp.ContinueWith(tsk => tsk.Result.GetResponseStream())
                  .ContinueWith((t) => YourMethodToHandleExceptions(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
                  .ContinueWith((Task<Stream> trs) =>
                       {
                            //Logic to update records
                       }
```

If the task 'tsk.Result.GetResponseStream()' throws an exception, 'YourMethodToHandleExceptions' will be run.  If there is no exception and the task IsCompleted or IsCancelled, then it will skip that portion of the continuation and procees with 'Logic to update records'.

As cited many times before, there is an excellent TPL article here (I've linked you to continuations): http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Continuations

Answer (score 0):

You can use async and await on 4.0 as well. This continuation nastiness goes away then.

If you don't want to do this you can untangle this a bit using a *single* continuation:

```
var taskResp = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(...);
taskResp.ContinueWith(tsk => {
 //Here, you can use tsk.Status, Exception and Result to get the data or the error.
});
```